# Proof of generalized Bernoulli's inequality for multiple real exponents and arguments.

Tags: analysis, inequality

I need some help proving the following inequality
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+x_i)^{a_i}\leq1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i,$$
for $a_i\geq0$ and $x_i>-1$, where $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\leq1$. The assumption with the sum of $a_i$ being equal or lower than $1$ gave me an idea to use either maximum or minimum of $x_i$ in place of all $x_i$, and use the classic inequality for the case when all $x_i$ are equal, but I cannot leave it later to get the desired inequality. I've also tried to use induction, but whenever I do so, I can't seem to use this assumption about the sum of $a_i$, and I always end up with too great of an estimation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\log$ on both sides, and we want to prove
$$\newcommand{\bp}[1]{{\left({#1}\right)}} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \log(1 + x_i) \leq \log\bp{1 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i}.$$
Now $f(x) := \log(1 + x)$ is concave, so by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \log(1 + x_i) \leq A \log\bp{1 + \frac{1}{A} \sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i},$$
where $A := \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. So it's enough to show that $A\log(1 + \frac1A x) \leq \log(1 + x)$ for $0 < A \leq 1$ and $\frac1A x > -1$.

Let $a := \frac1A$. We want to show that $\frac1a \log(1+ax) \leq \log(1+x)$ for $a\geq 1$ and $x > -\frac1a \geq -1$. Let $g(a) := \log(1+ax) - a\log(1+x)$. We want to prove $g(a) \leq 0$. We have
$$g''(a) = \frac{-x^2}{(1+ax)^2} \leq 0,$$
so $g$ is concave, and
$$g'(1) = \frac{x}{1+x} - \log(1+x).$$
If we prove that $g'(1) \leq 0$ then $g'(t) \leq 0$ for all $t\geq 1$, and $g(a) \leq g(1) = 0$, as desired.

Hence it's enough to show that $h(x) := \frac{x}{1+x} - \log(1+x) \leq 0$ for $x>-1$. We have
$$h'(x) = -\frac{x}{(1+x)^2},$$
which is positive for $x<0$ and negative for $x>0$, hence $h$ is maximized at $0$, and $h(x) \leq h(0) = 0$, as desired.

Comment: What happens if $1+\frac{1}{A}x<0$?

Comment: Oh, you are right. But $\frac1A \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i > -1$, since it's a weighted average and $x_i > -1$. So I can assume $\frac1A x > -1$, and everything still works, right? Well, in any case this approach is stupid given Gerard's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jensen inequality implies that $E(\log X)\leq \log E(X).$ With $a_0+\cdots+a_n=1,$ apply this to
$$X\sim a_0\delta_1+\sum_{i=1}^na_i\delta_{1+x_i}$$